# du -x still examines mounted filesystems when using wildcards

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, du

If I try

```
du -s -h -x /*
```

it will try to examine all filesystems (real and pseudo) mounted directly under /, e.g. /dev, /proc, /sys, /run, and /home (/home is on an extra partition).

I think it comes from the shell expansion of *, giving du a parameter list that explicitly includes these mount points.

Is there a way to make du not examine mounted filesystems, even when the mount points are contained in the parameter list ?

I really don't want to type all subdirs of / just to avoid them being in the parameter list.

Comment: I have a similar problem. As you say, "/*" is expanded *by the shell* to every subdir of the root dir. So "du -x /*" seems to "stay on the same filesystem" for each argument considered individually, which is not neccessarily the same as "the same filesystem as the root dir". "du -x /" will solve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still filter that using `mountpoint` (if available on your system):

```
for a in /*; do mountpoint -q -- "$a" || du -s -h -x "$a"; done
```

If `mountpoint` is not available but `stat` is (while `stat` is still not POSIX, it may be more common), you will have to compare the `stat` output manually:

```
rootdevice="$(stat -c %D /)"
for a in /*; do [ "$rootdevice" = "$(stat -c %D -- "$a")" ] && du -s -h -x "$a"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're right.  You are actually saying `du /dev`, `du /sys`, `du /usr`, `du /home` so the "-x" option is meaningless.

Why don't you loop over it? E.g. `find / -maxdepth 1 | egrep -v home|media` will list all dirs except home and media. Then you can pipe the output to a `while` loop to `du` it.

```
find / -maxdepth 1 | egrep -v home|media | while read f; do
  du -s -h -x "$f"; 
done
```

Comment: I would also need to manually type the egrep'ed exclusion list, as it's not only home and media. Looking again at my /, it's nearly 1/3 to exclude.

Yes, it's better than typing 2/3 to include, but still something I do not like to type in. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't use `*` in your `du` command. Use something akin to:

```
du -hx --max-depth=1| sort -h
```

or

```
du -hx / --max-depth=1| sort -h
```